# Asus Z-170 Deluxe - is M.2. entirely impractical or I don't understand the specs?

Tags: motherboard, bios, sata, m.2

If you scroll down on the [page](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/Z170-A/) to motherboard picture you will see 4x SATA 6Gb/s and Sata Express slots.

Now when I go to manual [page](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/Z170-DELUXE/E10627_Z170_DELUXE_UM_V2_WEB.pdf?_ga=1.213424028.983413308.1458949349) - to the section **3.6.8 Onboard Devices Configuration**(3-41 next page) within a bios I see a drop-down allowing to choose 'Sata EXpress' or 'M.2'.

My question is whether M.2 is entirely useless in a such configuration which eats all of the SATA ports in exchange for uber speeds of a single device? Do I understand correctly that using M.2 I can only connect one solid state drive?

Comment: It doesn't eat "all the ports" it eats 2 ports.  So unless you had planned, to use every single port, I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

It’s actually pretty clear how it works.

“M.2” setting: Both SATA mode as well as PCIe mode devices can be used in the M.2 slot. The SATA Express connector can only be used for PCIe mode devices.

“SATA Express” setting: Only PCIe mode devices can be used in the M.2 slot. The SATA Express connector can be used for both PCIe mode and SATA mode devices.

Most fast M.2 SSDs don’t use SATA but PCIe.